# Is it possible in C# for a unit test or code analysis to determine if a namespace is being used in a class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

As a business rule, we disallow the usage of a **specific** namespace when inside of this one other namespace.

Example:

```
using X.A;  //Allowed
using X.B;  //Not allowed

namespace X.C
{
    const string abc = X.A.MyClass.ABC; //Allowed
    const string def = X.B.MyClass.DEF; //Not allowed, because we are using X.B

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        string ghi = X.A.MyClass.GHI; //Allowed
        string jkl = X.B.MyClass.JKL; //Not allowed because we are using X.B
        string mno = "X.B.MyClass.MNO"; //Allowed, because we are not accessing X.B
    }
}
```

Is it possible to control this with a unit test, via code analysis, or both, so that we can more easily enforce this business rule, rather than relying on code review, which can easily miss this sort of thing? Assuming that it is possible, how would you go about doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of such a rule? This does not really seem useful. Why don’t you just remove the assembly reference instead?

Comment: Unit tests are for verifying _results_, not _implementation_.  Code analysis could probably be used to detect this usage.  If you want to now ask _how_ it can be done please add that to your question and specify _which_ code analysis tool you want to use.

Comment: Two or more assemblies can share the same namespace hierarchy. You can put `X.A` in one dll and `X.B` in another. But really, controlling access by namespace is awkward and you'll be fighting the tool to keep it working.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to not have an assembly reference to `X.B` in `X.C`. Aside from that, you could probably use a [Roslyn code analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx) to enforce this.

Comment: As already explained, if you want to ensure that a given layer don't use another layer, the best solution is to put that layer in its own assembly and adjust references such that X.B is not available from the assembly that defined X.C.

Comment: Here's me expecting that if someone is asking "is it possible" that would imply "how would it be done", but I digress.  As for the purpose of this rule, the X.C assembly itself currently requires X.B for portions of its code (and needs refactoring), but there is a specific folder that cannot access X.B, thus not allowing us to remove the assembly reference (yet).  In addition to that, programmers that are new to our framework regularly want to re-add the assembly, which tends to be missed in code review.  As for which code analysis tool, I would lean toward using Roslyn, if possible.

Comment: Understand your pain, but I was you, I would get someone to refactor the code X.C that uses X.B. Then getting rid of X.B all together.

Comment: Ultimately, I do understand that it would probably be best to remove the assembly reference.  The entire project was poorly designed from the start, in that regard, I was looking more as as stop-gap measure, as I do not currently have the authorization to change that project, but I could add unit tests/code analysis until the project is redesigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such rule is possible with the tool NDepend [that let's write code rule through C# LINQ queries](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL), and [check such rules live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/validating-cqlinq-code-rules-in-visual-studio) and [in your Build Process](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/customize-ndepend-report#CQLRule).

Concretely such rule could look like:

```
warnif count > 0 from n in Namespaces where 
 n.IsUsing ("NUnit.Core.Extensibility") &&
(n.Name == @"NUnit.Core.Builders")
select new { n, n.NbLinesOfCode }
// the namespace NUnit.Core.Builders
// shouldn't use directly 
// the namespace NUnit.Core.Extensibility
// because (TODO insert your reason)
```

...and this rule can be edited and executed / enforced live in Visual Studio.
[image: NDepend Namespace Rule Edited in Visual Studio]

Actually you can generate such code rule with a single click from the [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph) or from the [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm):

[image: NDepend Dependency Graph]

Such rule rule can also be written and enforced in unit-tests since NDepend provides and [API](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html).

You might also be interested by our [white books concerning structuring code through namespaces and assemblies](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/white-books).

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend.*